# Laravel get number of failed login attempt

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 just trying to get the number of failed login attempt from controller as shown below.. It always returns 0 but `hasTooManyLoginAttempts` works fine. anyone has any ideas?

In `LoginController.php`

```
protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
{
    return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
        $this->throttleKey($request), 3, 1
    );
}
```

Above code works fine by locking user for 1 minute if there is failed login attempt of 3 times. But I want to get the count of login attempt.based on below code

```
public function tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $decayMinutes = 1)
{

    echo $this->attempts($key);
    exit;

    if ($this->cache->has($key.':lockout')) {
        return true;
    }

    if ($this->attempts($key) > $maxAttempts) {
        $this->lockout($key, $decayMinutes);

        $this->resetAttempts($key);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

`echo $this->attempts($key);` always returns 0.how do we figure out this?

Comment: Which Laravel version is it ?

Comment: laravel 5.4.......

Comment: Listen for the event on `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed`, and do something when it fires.

Comment: Do not use `echo` && `exit`, use [`dd()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd)

Answer (score 2):

Well `$this->attempts($key)` does actually return the number of attempt.  But the thing is that it will always return 1 because you `dd()` it and it gets the number from the cache.

So if you reload your page after your failed attempt, the cache will get cleared and it'll display 0 in your case (it displays 0 because `tooManyAttempts` is called from `hasTooManyLoginAttempts` in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, before `$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);` at line 48).

What I did was I created a file in the public folder called "test.txt", then I located the `incrementLoginAttempts` function, which lies in the `ThrottlesLogins` trait (line 32, laravel 5.4), and finally I put this in this function : `file_put_contents('test.txt', $this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey($request)));` (or just use the `\Log::info(...)` helper).

It allows you to check the number of failed login attempt so you can just chain fail and watch the number increase.  So `$this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey($request))`, or `$this->attempts($key)` does return the right number.

I might have forgotten something because I did a quick research in the code but it basically explains why your value was "always" the same :-).

Answer (score 1):

Try it (in LoginController.php):

```
$this->limiter()->attempts($this->throttleKey($request));
```

If `hasTooManyLoginAttempts` function did. The result is 0. You read function `tooManyAttempts` at class `RateLimiter` to learn more.